# Show that $V_G: L^2(G\times G, \mu \times \mu)\to L^2(G\times G, \mu \times \mu)$ defined by $V_G(f)(x,y) = f(xy,y)$ is well-defined

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group and let $\mu$ be a right Haar measure on $G$. Then $\mu\times \mu$ (the Radon product of measures) is a right Haar measure on $G \times G$ and we can define the operator

$$V_G: L^2(G\times G, \mu \times \mu)\to L^2(G\times G, \mu \times \mu)$$

by $$V_G(f)(x,y) = f(xy,y)$$
where $f$ is a measurable square integrable function on $G \times G$ and $x,y \in G$.

Is it true that $V_G$ is well-defined? I.e. if $f= g$ almost everywhere, then is it true that
$V_G(f)= V_G(g)$ almost everywhere?

Let $f \in C_c(G \times G)$. By proposition 7.22 of Folland's book "Real analysis", we can apply a version of Fubini's theorem without any assumptions on the $\sigma$-finiteness of the spaces. We obtain

\begin{align*}\int_{G\times G} |V_G(f)(x,y)|^2 (\mu \times \mu)(dx,dy) &= \int_{G \times G} |f(xy, y)|^2(\mu\times \mu)(dx,dy)\\
&= \int_G \left(\int_G |f(xy,y)|^2\mu(dx)\right) \mu(dy)\\
&= \int_G \left(\int_G |f(x,y)|^2 \mu(dx)\right)\mu(dy)\\
&= \int_{G \times G} |f(x,y)|^2 (\mu\times \mu)(dx,dy)\end{align*}

so it follows that $\|V_G(f)\|_2 = \|f\|_2$ for $f \in C_c(G \times G)$. We thus obtain an isometric mapping
$$V_G: C_c(G \times G)\to L^2(G \times G)$$
so at least the mapping is well-defined on $C_c(G \times G)$. Somehow I want to invoke density of $C_c(G \times G)$ in $L^2(G \times G)$ to conclude.

---

The above question is based on the following fragment in Timmerman's book "An invitation to quantum groups and duality":

[image]

---

Comment: Is the product of measures even well defined in the non-$\sigma$-finite case?  I guess you choose the right Haar measure on $G \times G$, normalised so that it satisfies the product condition.

Comment: If you use the borel sigma algebra and $G$ is not separable then the group multiplication law need not be measurable (this is related to the "Nedoma pathology"). If one uses the Baire sigma algebra instead then things are generally OK even in the inseparable case.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, this is the "Radon product" of measures.

Comment: @TerryTao By assumption, the multiplication $G \times G \to G$ is continuous, and thus measurable.

Comment: The subtlety here is that the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $G \times G$ can be strictly larger than the product of the Borel $\sigma$ algebras on $G$ separately.  For instance on the uncountable torus $G = {\bf T}^{\bf R}$, the diagonal of $G \times G$ is measurable in the former but not the latter.   The Baire algebra does not encounter this Nedoma pathology, however, and also enjoys a good Riesz representation theorem and a notion of a Radon measure: see my recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.00681 with Jamneshan.

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks. Let's fix some notation. Let $\mathscr{B}_G$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra related to the locally compact space $G$. Then by assumption $f$ is $\mathscr{B}_{G \times G}$-measurable. Also $(x,y) \mapsto f(xy,y)$ is $\mathscr{B}_{G \times G}$-measurable because it is the composition of the homeomorphism $G \times G \to G \times G: (x,y) \mapsto (xy,y)$ with $f$, so I still don't understand where the measurability problem kicks in.

Comment: $\mu \times \mu$ denotes the Radon product here. It is defined as follows: Given $f \in C_c(G \times G)$, one can show that $f$ is $\mathscr{B}_G \otimes \mathscr{B}_G$-measurable so we can look at the well-defined linear functional $C_c(G \times G) \to \mathbb{C}: f \mapsto \int_G \int_G f(x,y) \mu(dx)\mu(dy) = \int_G \int_G f(x,y) \mu(dy)\mu(dx)$ and the Riesz representation theorem gives us an associated positive Radon measure $\mu \times \mu$.

Comment: These calculations are fine for $f \in C_c(G \times G)$.  For $f \in L^2(G \times G)$ one can canonically extend the operator $V_G$ to a unitary operator on $L^2(G \times G)$ by density but it will not quite be given by the formula $V_G(f)(x,y) = f(xy,y)$ for arbitrary $f \in L^2(G \times G)$ represented as a ${\mathcal B}_{G \times G}$-measurable function due to the non-measurability of the shift $(x,y) \mapsto (xy,y)$ at this level of generality.  (However, every $f \in L^2(G \times G)$ has a representative measurable in the Baire product algebra, and at this level the formula works fine.)

Comment: (More precisely, the difficulty is non-measurability in a sigma-algebra in which the Fubini-Tonelli theorem applies for all absolutely integrable functions (not just the continuous compactly supported ones).)

Comment: @Terry Tao Thanks for the discussion! I believe it is clear now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to demur from the comments, and say that actually everything works fine, with appropriate (but standard) definitions.  The original question referenced [Folland's Real Analysis book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Real+Analysis%3A+Modern+Techniques+and+Their+Applications%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471317166), so I'll make references to that to start with.

The first "problem" is that with $\mathcal B_G$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on $G$, we don't necessarily have that $\mathcal B_G \times \mathcal B_G = \mathcal B_{G\times G}$, unless $G$ is second countable.  The standard way to "fix" this is to define a Radon measure on $G\times G$ to satisfy
$$ \int_{G\times G} f(x,y) \ d(\mu\hat\times\mu)(x,y) = \int_G \int_G f(x,y) \ d\mu(x) \ d\mu(y) $$
for all continuous compactly supported $f$.  (So $\mu\hat\times\mu$ is built from the Riesz representation theorem, and not directly as a product measure).  See Section 7.4 in Folland.

When $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then essentially everything works as we might hope: Theorem 7.27 in Folland is the statement of the Fubini--Tonelli Theorem, showing for example that if $f\in L^1(\mu\hat\times\mu)$ then $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is in $L^1(\mu)$ for almost all $y$, and
$$ \int f d(\mu\hat\times\mu) = \int\int f(x,y) \ d\mu(x) \ d\mu(y), $$
(and the other way around).  This formula also holds for any positive, Borel measurable function on $G\times G$ (and so $\mu\hat\times\mu$ extends the usual meaning of $\mu\times\mu$).

Thus, given $f\in L^2(\mu\hat\times\mu)$ (meaning that I take any function $f:G\times G\rightarrow\mathbb C$ with $\int |f|^2 < \infty$ and identify $f$ with its equivalence class) then as $\alpha:G\times G\ni (x,y) \mapsto (xy,y)\in G\times G$ is a continuous homeomorphism, $f\circ\alpha$ is Borel, and by Fubini--Tollelli applied to $|f\circ\alpha|^2$, we can invoke right-invariance:
\begin{align*}
\int |f\circ\alpha|^2 \ d(\mu\hat\times\mu)
= \int \int |f(xy,y)| \ d\mu(x) \ d\mu(y)
= \int \int |f(x,y)| \ d\mu(x) \ d\mu(y)
= \int |f|^2 \ d(\mu\hat\times\mu)
\end{align*}
So $V$ is an isometry (and then clearly a unitary, as $V^{-1}=V^*$ has a similar form).

(To concretely answer the original question, if $f=0$ almost everything for $\mu\hat\times\mu$ then the same is true of $f\circ\alpha$, and so $V$ is indeed well-defined.)

To show that $L^2(\mu\hat\times\mu) = L^2(\mu)\otimes L^2(\mu)$ one uses that $C_c(G\times G)$ is dense is both, and that the natural inner-products agree.  (See Proposition 7.9 in Folland).

Finally, what about the non $\sigma$-finite case?  This is dealt with by the "Interlude", section 2.3 in [Folland's Harmonic Analysis book](https://www.routledge.com/A-Course-in-Abstract-Harmonic-Analysis/Folland/p/book/9781498727136).  Fubini--Tonelli still holds if we can work in a $\sigma$-compact subset of $G\times G$.  We are only interested in, say, $L^p$ spaces, and then $f\in L^p$ will always vanish outside of a $\sigma$-compact subset.  Indeed, things are very nice for a locally compact group $G$ as then there is a $\sigma$-compact open and closed subgroup $G_0$, and we can write $G$ as the product of cosets of $G_0$.

---

A slightly different perspective if afforded by Cohn's book [Measure Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6956-8) see Section 9.4 for convolution.  In particular, Lemma 9.4.3 exactly considers the analogue for the left Haar measure.  Cohn's presentation is slightly slicker as he proves Theorem 7.6.7 which is a version of Fubini for arbitrary Radon measures, and then Lemma 9.4.2 shows that when applied to a Haar measure, the hypotheses are always satisfied.

Comment: So the calculation in my OP holds for any $f\in L^2$? Not just $f\in C_c$?

Comment: Yes: this is almost the same as the big displayed equation in my answer.  Compare to how Folland and Cohn treat convolution of $L^1$ functions.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Am I correct if I say that the version of Fubini in Cohn's book follows (relatively quickly) from the version in Folland's book, or are there still other technicalities that I don't see? Roughly the argument should go as follows: if $f$ is supported in a measurable rectangle $E \times F$ with $\sigma$-finite sides, then the integral over $X \times Y$ equals the integral of $E \times F$ and on this we can apply $\sigma$-finite Fubini from Folland.

Comment: I also started a bounty because I think this exceptional answer deserves some kind of reward!

Comment: Yes, I believe that is exactly right!  If you examine the _proofs_ in either book, then you actually start with _finite_ measures, and then appeal to a summation argument to deal with the $\sigma$-finite case.  I cannot say why Folland doesn't quite state the result in full generality.  (The notes in Folland suggest also looking at Hewitt and Ross: I haven't done this, but it might be interesting.)

Comment: Thanks again for the help!